# vba Function Returned value after call

Tags: vba, function, memory

I have in one module a sub that calls a function in another module and that function is publicly defined, after calling the function i store its returned value into a variable.

**my question is** :
does the function retain its value in memory after being called by that sub? if so i want to clean it from the memory based on its type (example: `set myFunct = nothing`) if it returns an object.

[image]

Comment: as for my knowledge the function in itself isn't a variable, it just supplies a value or a reference to a variable and then it "dies" just after. you can check it in Locals window

Comment: The scope of VBA variables is well documented on this site: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/141693

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VBA implements [Reference counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) to clean the memory using a "Garbage Collector"

When you call a function, it doesn't matter whether this function is *private* or *public*. What matters is, if inside the function you use a *global* or a *local* variable for your object. In your case it looks like it's *local*.

Your *local* variable is thus only referenced in your function, so its *reference counter* = 1.

At the moment your variable becomes out-of-scope, ie when the function ends and returns the value, **the reference counter of the object is decremented and becomes 0**. 
Although the object is still physically present in memory, it is not addressable anymore, becomes useless, and is therefore candidate for the garbage collector.

When you code `Set theobject_inside_function = nothing` you are just *explicitly* decrementing the reference counter. So it is useless to do it inside your function because VBA will  do it for you once the function will end.

You can also read [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2004/04/28/when-are-you-required-to-set-objects-to-nothing/), it's old but still breaking a lot of myths regarding variable cleaning in VB

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, i have now a better picture about the Garbage collection. this also reminds me to clean my Garbage Too :)

Answer (score 0):

from what i noticed as long as there is a variable linked to the function (meaning the value of that variable comes from the function output ) the function stays alive ... i tested that. 
please leave any comments that help us learn more

Comment: well...never studied computer science on university but for my opinion the function never exist on RAM (like variables does - pointed to "stack memory" if ive translated it right) functions executed in CPU on running time and when the function finished running it does not exist anymore (in CPU) and you can see it on task manager when running "heavy" function cores work hard, when they finish cpu decreasing dramatically. interesting question to me  but probabley for somone who learned computer science in a dissent university it is a basic question...